# appPackage and appActivity cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, mobile, automation, appium

I'm trying to set up mobile automation, using appium with android, but the below commands are not working for appPackage and appActivity

dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.appPackage, "com.android.calculator2");
        dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.appActivity, "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");

I get the following error for appPackage and appActivity - Cannot be resolved or is not a field.
I have even tried APP_PACKAGE and APP_ACTIVITY. Did not work. What are the arguments written as? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

APP_PACKAGE and APP_ACTIVITY are not included in MobileCapabilityType. You need to write in quotation as mentioned in below code snippet.

```
dc.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2"); 
dc.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try `AndroidMobileCapabilityType` instead

```
dc.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "io.appium.android.apis");
dc.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, ".ApiDemos");
```